# Wordpress shortcode is being inserted before content

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I know we have have to return the shortcode but I'm trying to use custom templates and the shortcode is being inserted before the content in the wysiwyg editor when its actually at the end of the content:

Here is my shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('test_temp', 'temp_handler');

function temp_handler($atts) { 
   ob_start();
   load_template(TEMPLATES_PATH . templates/test.php');
   return ob_get_contents();

}
```

here is what test.php looks like:

```
 <div class="testDiv">Here is my test template</div>
```

What else can I do so the short code is not inserted before the content?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You mean load template after return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_shortcode('test_temp', 'temp_handler');

function temp_handler($atts) { 
   ob_start();
   load_template(TEMPLATES_PATH . templates/test.php');
   $ret = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   return $ret;
}
```

Your idea to use output buffering to load template files is a good idea and a common practice for Wordpress shortcodes. However, it looks odd to me that you don't end the output buffering anywhere in your provided code,  `ob_end_clean()`, which leads me to believe that your output buffering is just not setup perfectly.

Generally speaking, Wordpress will run your function and replace your shortcode tag with the output. If the output of your function is instead showing up somewhere else on the page (particularly if it is showing up above the area where it should be) then your function must be outputting content *as Wordpress is running it* (in your case, it must not be output buffering as expected).

Note: The `load_template` function uses `require_once` by default, which means you'll only be able to use your shortcode once on the page. Instead, I recommend using: `load_template(TEMPLATES_PATH . templates/test.php',` **false**`);`